# Curvature of a 3D trajectory for which I know data points

Tags: 3d, data-analysis, curvature

In order to simulate an airplane model, I need to change its orientation knowing the curvature of its trajectory.

The simulator gives me the plane position, so in order to perform my orientation calculus I need to know the curvature of the trajectory.

So, having its trajectory history (I can choose how many previous positions use), how can I calculate the curvature of this 3D trajectory?

Answer (score 2):

In a real-life situation, you'll probably want to take redundant measurements and do a fit and/or remove outliers and things like that to improve the robustness, but if you regard the measurements as exact, three positions suffice. Measure them at times $t=-\Delta t,0,\Delta t$, call the results $x_{-1},x_0,x_1$, respectively, and calculate the curvature $\kappa$ according to

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\dot x&\simeq&\frac12\frac {x_1-x_{-1}}{\Delta t}\;,\\
\ddot x&\simeq&\frac{x_1+x_{-1}-2x_0}{\Delta t^2}\;,\\
\kappa&=&\frac{\left|\ddot x_\perp\right|}{\left|\dot x\right|^2}=
\frac{\left|\ddot x-\frac{\ddot x\cdot\dot x}{\dot x\cdot\dot x}\dot x\right|}{\left|\dot x\right|^2}=
\frac{\left|\ddot x\left(\dot x\cdot\dot x\right)-\left(\ddot x\cdot\dot x\right)\dot x\right|}{\left(\dot x\cdot\dot x\right)\left(\dot x\cdot\dot x\right)}\;.
\end{eqnarray}
$$

(The $\Delta t$ drops out, so you might as well leave it out; it's just there so that $\dot x$ and $\ddot x$ have their usual meanings.)